# I cannot write into SQL Server 2008 R2 express edition from C#

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

There is no error, the dataset is getting updated, but the database is **not updated**.

I am using Windows authentication in connection string to the database. I have given accept changes on update.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the `User Instances` and `AttachDbFileName` options in your connection string? If so I will bet that you are actually connected to two different copies of your database. You need to make sure you are connecting to the same copy - I would suggest manually attaching the database on your Express instance, and always connecting to that *without* the use of `User Instances` and `AttachDbFileName`.

If this is not the case, please show the connection string you are using in C# and how you are validating that the data is not updated (e.g. you are probably using a different application and/or connection string for that).

The `User Instances` feature is actually deprecated for future development work. In SQL Server 2012 this is replaced with SqlLocalDb.